# JS IE Error (Object doesn't support property or method 'select')

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Trying to copy some info to clipboard.

In Chrome and others works fine, In IE I get the error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'select'"

html:

```
<textarea name="wtBodyInpt" id="wtBodyInpt">Copy This</textarea>
```

JS:

```
function copyBodyToClipboard (BodyInpt) {
   // Select text inside element
   BodyInpt.focus();
   BodyInpt.select();
   // Copy text to clipboard
   document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```
copyBodyToClipboard(wtBodyInpt)
```

Comment: Why should this work in any browser? `BodyInpt` is a string. And a string has no `.focus()` or `.select()` methods.

Comment: As already suggested by @Andreas it looks like there are some logical mistakes in the sample code. can you please again try to check it? If the issue persists then can you please share the exact code which is working in Chrome but giving an error in IE? It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Edited the post, The BodyInpt wasnt a string but the ID of the <texarea> it was copied from Outsystems that's why it looked like a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object of the element by accessing the element using its ID or name.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<p>Try to paste the text by pressing ctrl + v in a different window, to see the effect.</p>


<textarea name="wtBodyInpt" id="wtBodyInpt">Copy This Text</textarea>

<p>The document.execCommand() method is not supported in IE8 and earlier.</p>

<script>
function copyBodyToClipboard (element) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(element);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
 
}
var str="wtBodyInpt";
copyBodyToClipboard (str)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]